# Native Query for delete functionality

Tags: sql

I have to write a native delete query.
I have to delete a row based on Id which is selected based on  a condition from another table

```
@Query(nativeQuery= true , value = "Delete from tableA where  idA (select id from Table B where name = :name")
```

But the native Query is framed wrongly.
Pls help

Comment: You are missing something like `in` in the `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
Delete from tableA 
where idA IN (select id from Table B where name = :name)
          ^^----- add this             and that -------^
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.